# Java query for Cassandra not returning right values

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have a Java application which reads data from a Cassandra db.
I'm running a lot of trial queries to test my app: some of them work, some other don't, whereas the same not-working queries are completely right if run in DBeaver.

Why my app is not always able to fetch the data from Cassandra?

I'm not posting code because is pretty long, I just wanted to know if there is some particular aspect I have to care about when dealing with Cassandra from Java.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing your data model, query, and cluster size, but this could be indicative of consistency issues.

The driver default consistency level is LOCAL_ONE. If you have inconsistent (un-repaired) data, you could end up querying a replica that does not have the data. In another context with different query plan or higher consistency, you might see the data.

You can test this by issuing the query at a higher consistency level. If you find this returns the data, you will want to look into repairing these tables.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Reading what you wrote, I can assume that possibly my Java app could not be wrong, am I correct? I have an exam tomorrow where I need to present this app. The db is not under my control. I just need the code to be correct. Other aspects are not under my control. What do you think?

Comment: Have a look at the different consistency levels cassandra supports. The default from the driver might be LOCAL_ONE.

Even if your tables are uncorrupted, a write to a column familiy with higher replication factor than 1 might hit a different replica which has not the most current data yet. This happens easily in cassandra, immediate read after write might give stale data.

Try QUORUM to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite possible that you are not giving enough attention to how you will wrap your arguments in query in quotes.

Comment: You're right. But I expressed myself too poorly. What I did mean, was that some queries run correctly, but sometimes the same queries do not return values. But the prepareStatement and BoundStatement do not change, of course. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Okay I understand your question now.
But I would just keep my answer here in case someone in future might benefit from it.